# Disabling smooth scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, panel

I have a Panel in which a VerticalScroll is used. When the user clicks the VerticalScroll and drags it, the VerticalScroll scrolls smoothly. This is what I do not want to have. Rather than scrolling smoothly, I would like the VerticalScroll to scroll in discrete steps, to be precise in the same steps as I specified in the property SmallChange. How can I do that?

Edit: It basically seems to work when overriding the OnPaint method of the Panel, but how can I suppress the call to base.OnPaint conditionally?

This code sets the position of the Vertical Scroll to the right value:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int v = this.VerticalScroll.Value;
        this.VerticalScroll.Value = Math.Max(0, Form1.AlignFileButtonHeight(v, v + 1));
    }
```

But it has the effect that the window "blinks" for an instant! How can I avoid that?

Edit: The best result I have achieved so far, I have achieved by overriding the OnScroll method:

```
    protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se)
    {
        if (se.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbTrack)
        {
            int v = se.NewValue;
            v = Math.Max(0, Form1.AlignFileButtonHeight(v, v + 1));
            this.VerticalScroll.Value = v;
            this.Refresh();
            se.NewValue = v;
            base.OnScroll(se);
            this.Refresh();
            base.OnScroll(se);
        }
    }
```

It still blinks a bit, but not as much as when overriding the OnPaint method. However, I'd like to get rid of blinking entirely.

Edit: I also tried this, with only very limited success.

```
    protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se)
    {
        if (se.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbTrack && se.NewValue != se.OldValue)
        {
            int diff = se.NewValue - se.OldValue;

            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                int x = c.Location.X;
                int y = c.Location.Y;

                y = y + diff;

                c.Location = new Point(x, y);
            }

            if (se.NewValue % Form1.fileButtonHeight == 0)
            {
                foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
                {
                    int x = c.Location.X;
                    int y = c.Location.Y;

                    y = y + (diff < 0 ? 1 : -1) * Form1.fileButtonHeight;

                    c.Location = new Point(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This downvote is not justified since I did make several attempts at achieving this.

Comment: What did you do? I don't see any "proof" in your question body. You just described your problem, nothing more. And "How can I do that?" without any addition also stated this for me.

Comment: The problem is simply that the approaches I tried have not worked - such as catching the Scroll event and manually setting the scroll bar position in the event handler to a multiple of the value I entered in the property SmallChange.

Comment: The basic job that Panel does is adjust the Location property of its child controls when you operate the scrollbar.  So nothing to do with Paint.  This is not behavior that is overridable, you don't have any use for Panel at all when you need this.  You'd have to create your own panel-like control, that has to start at its base class.  Use the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ScrollableControl.cs,24feec50034d1f25) to have a valid shot at it.  Character-building exercise.